# What does 契約期間:2年 mean?

Tags: meaning

When looking for an apartment, I often see 契約期間:2年 written. What does it  mean? I have to make a contract for 2 years and then it can be renewed or extended with some extra renewal cost? Can I rent just for 1 year?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a sentence of Japanese, it just means the contract is valid for two years.

Practically, first you have to check whether it's 普通借家契約 or 定期借家契約. The latter is uncommon but it means you cannot extend the contract and have to leave your apartment after the contract expires (3 years, for example). See: [「普通借家契約」と「定期借家契約」](http://www.fudousan.or.jp/kiso/rent/shakka.html)

Unless explicitly mentioned as **定期**, it's 普通借家契約, which means you can basically rent the apartment as long as you want. Still, you need to renew your contract usually every two years. You may be charged additional 1 or 2 months of rent money under the name of 契約更新料 ("contract renewal fee") unless otherwise mentioned as 更新料無料. In any case, you can leave your apartment before two years pass without penalty provided you notify the owner one month prior to the leaving date.

But there may be exceptions on a case-by-case basis, so you need to understand the contract. You can have a detailed explanation before you make a contract.

Comment: When there is 管理費等 10,000円 written, it must be paid every month?

Comment: @SingleFighter Yes, it's basically part of the monthly payment. (sorry for the late reply)

Answer (score 1):

In japan You usually have a minimum contract of 1 or 2 years. If you leave earlier you will need to pay a fee worth 1-3 month rent. There is probably no problem in staying longer. If you need to renew every time is a question better asked to the owner. But it's probably not an immediate problem.

Where I stayed in my first apartment in Japan, no renewal was required, but if I didn't stay at least 1 year(I didn't) I had to pay 3 month rent(or so said contract I signed, but the owner said I didn't have to pay when I left. lucky me).

Comment: So what does that word mean?

Comment: @SingleFighter 契約期間 means "contract duration"

Comment: Yes. I know, but can I rent just for 1 year when 契約期間:2年 is written?

Comment: @SingleFighter No. You can try to negotiate, but they probably won't accept unless really desperate for people. Usually the way it goes is the building hire a　company to find people for them. And you have to deal with that company. If you negotiate with them, they might relay your question to the owner.

Comment: Unless you apply in a very big building in a major city, the owners tend to be nice old folks taking it easy. They usually fill the requirement forms(given to them by the company) without much after thoughts, and will easily be negotiated with.

Comment: Are you sure about having to stay a minimum of two or whatever years? I rented out my place and the people left after 6 months, and I certainly didn't get any extra cash out of them.

Comment: @KenY-N It depends on the contract. That's how it was for me. If you don't put it on your contract, then of course they won't give you money.